# get real g.co url

Tags: google-maps

I got on my DB, allot like this urls

http://g.co/maps/8s4th

but i need to get the real googlpe maps address so i can embed it. Someone ha any idea how to do this?

i need the real one

http://maps.google.com.mx/maps?q=monterrey&hl=es&ie=UTF8&sll=23.625269,-102.540613&sspn=26.141296,41.616211&hnear=Monterrey,+Nuevo+León&t=h&z=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously with ajax I CAN'T, but i do it with PHP i leave the code i hope it help

```
<?
$url = "http://g.co/maps/rdu3e";
$response = get_headers($url, 1);
print_r($response['Location']);
?>
```

Comment: Is it because of cross site issues? When I posted my answer, I had forgotten about that. I don't do much client side stuff, sorry.

Comment: @xxpor no problem men, i also know that ajax can't call offsite websites but i forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Do a GET to the g.co, look at the Location: in the 301 response you receive.

Comment: I do this with ajax or php? And how?

Comment: @Ernesto You do it with an HTTP request. How you do that is up to you. You can do it with AJAX client side, or PHP (or C# or Ruby or whatever) on the server side.